# How to export a GMF diagram outside eclipse?

Tags: papyrus

One of the features of Papyrus that I find really useful is the ability to programmatically interrogate the UML models that it creates by using the UML2 runtime outside the Eclipse UI. This is great for running simple tools to, e.g., produce documentation using POI or write model driven configuration for the Talend MDM tool. However, while traversing and processing the model tree is easily achieved by loading up the resources in a resource set, manipulating the diagrams in the .notation files has proven to be more of a challenge.

I have got to the point (by examining the source for `org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.export.ExportAllDiagrams`) where I can load all the resources and find the `Diagram` elements from the .notation file thus:

```
    File uml = new File(model + ".uml");
    File di = new File(model + ".di");
    File notation = new File(model + ".notation");
    URI umlUri = URI.createFileURI(uml.getAbsolutePath());
    URI diUri = URI.createFileURI(di.getAbsolutePath());
    URI notationUri = URI.createFileURI(notation.getAbsolutePath());

    final ModelSet resourceSet = new ModelSet();

    resourceSet.getPackageRegistry().put(UMLPackage.eNS_URI, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
    resourceSet.getPackageRegistry().put(NotationPackage.eNS_URI, NotationPackage.eINSTANCE);

    resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(Resource.Factory.Registry.DEFAULT_EXTENSION, new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
    resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("notation", new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
    resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);

    try {
        resourceSet.getLoadOptions().put(XMLResource.OPTION_DEFER_IDREF_RESOLUTION, true);
        resourceSet.getLoadOptions().put(XMLResource.OPTION_DEFER_ATTACHMENT, true);

        resourceSet.getResource(diUri, true);
        resourceSet.getResource(umlUri, true);
        resourceSet.getResource(notationUri, true);

        List<Diagram> diagrams = new ArrayList<Diagram>();
        for (Iterator<Notifier> i = resourceSet.getAllContents(); i.hasNext();) {
            Notifier n = i.next();
            if (n instanceof Diagram) {
                diagrams.add((Diagram) n);
            }
        }

        //export(diagrams);
    } finally {
        // Unload the resource set so that we don't leak loads of UML content in the CacheAdapter
        unload(resourceSet);
    }
```

However, the `ExportAllDiagrams` class ultimately uses `org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render.util.CopyToImageUtil` to render the diagram, at which point it fails because it relies on the `DiagramUIRenderPlugin` and `DiagramUIRenderPlugin.getInstance()` returns null.

I then had a look at `org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.render.clipboard.DiagramSVGGenerator` but had similar problems with the need for various eclipse plugins to be initialised.

I have no experience of the Eclipse plugin system but I am assuming that that the platform loads and initialises plugins and, therefore, the approaches tried so far need to be running within Eclipse GUI environment in order to work. Is there any other method that could be used to easily render the diagrams to SVG without relying on the whole of the Eclipse runtime?